# Getting coords of a place from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

I need to get coordinates of a place from OSM. When I search OSM by name I get the output like this:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=N&osmid=6346201933&class=tourism&format=json

I am trying to figure out how to format my API call. I have couple parameters to search for such as:

- localname
- state

but I believe the API also needs OSM ID, which I'm not sure where I can get. A bit lost here...

Comment: There's a reason this hasn't been answered, and sticking a bounty on a question isn't going to magically make it a good question. Clarify your inputs and desired outputs; provide a clear problem statement; specify in the question what attempts you have made to solve the problem; do not rely on external links as important parts of your question. Someone with 13k rep should know this already.

Comment: May I point out the obvious. There's API reference documentation for Nominatim: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The api documentation describes this](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#parameters):

https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/

I quote from the documentation:

The search API has the following format:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?<params>
```

[Example JSON with address details](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#json-with-address-details):

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=bakery+in+berlin+wedding&format=json&limit=1
```

You get the output:

[image: JSON with address details]

> I need to get coordinates of a place from OSM.

As you can see from the above image, the json contains the lat, lon, and osm_id, which you can parse from the json response.

If you see the [documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/), there is detailed information on the different ways you can make requests, and the format of output parameters.

In your case, you mention you would like to use the local name and state. I do not know what you mean by local name,
but the parameters section clearly shows how you can use street, city, county, state, country and postal code.

If you get stuck, please post a detailed question of what you're trying to do, and I'm sure more people would be glad to help.